# Watch for changes in service and update component in angular2, typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a component and a service. I want to notify my component whenever a boolean property in my service changes. I think I should use Observable and Observer from rxjs.

I made the service and component which is not working as expected.

*AppComponent.ts*

```
import {  Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserData } from 'user-data.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: '<div></div>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    constructor(public userData: UserData) {
       userData.isLoggedIn.subscribe(isLoggedIn => {
           this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
       });//???
    }
    ???
}
```

*UserDataService.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserData {
    isLoggedIn: Observable<boolean>; // ???
    observer: Observer<boolean>; // ??? giving an error in tsc (Type 'Observer' is not generic)
    constructor() {
        this.isLoggedIn = new Observable(observer => 
           this.observer = observer
        ).share(); ///???
    }
    changeLoginStatus (isLoggedIn: boolean) { // function called from login/logout actions
        this.observer.next(isLoggedIn); // ??? not sure
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `BehaviorSubject` with an initial value:

```
export class UserData {
  isLoggedIn: Subject<bool> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  changeLoginStatus (isLoggedIn: boolean) { 
    this.isLoggedIn.next(isLoggedIn); // ??? not sure
  } 
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

As @KonradGarus suggested, the `Subject` should be kept private.

```
export class UserData {
  private isLoggedIn: Subject<bool> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  isLoggedIn$ = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
  changeLoginStatus (isLoggedIn: boolean) { 
    this.isLoggedIn.next(isLoggedIn); 
  } 
}
```

The cookbook linked above also contains a full example where the `Subject` is kept private.

Comment: next method is on type Observer and not on Observable

Comment: Sorry, change the type to `Subject` instead.

Comment: When I am trying to use new BehaviorSubject(false); I am getting a  404 on rxjs . http://localhost:8080/node_modules/rxjs/ 404 (Not Found). but I could use 'Subject' from rxjs.
import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs'; is throwing error while import { Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject'; works.  Any Idea??

Comment: `import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject';`

Comment: 'subject' is not available in rxjs. Not sure why. But changing BehaviorSubject to Subject . ie isLoggedIn: Subject<bool> = new Subject<boolean>(); solved the issue

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` definitely exists. Not sure what's wrong. You can also use `Subject`. The advantage of `BehaviorSubject` is, that new subscribers immediately get the last emitted value. With `Subject` if a component subscribes after an event was emitted, it doesn't get any state until another event is emitted. That's not always bad but `BehaviorSubject` is sometimes quite convenient.

Comment: While we're at it, the common recommendation is to expose `Observable` and keep the `Subject` private.

Comment: @KonradGarus I also think this is a good idea, but I try to keep it simple for the first steps.